# Making a list out of list based on condition

Tags: python

I have a list of 2 different values:

```
data = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1514764800, 1514851200, 1514937600, 1515024000, 1515110400, 1515196800, 1515283200, 1515369600, 1515456000,]]
```

Now I want to create a list from `list_of_values[0]` based on a condition of `list_of_values[1]`
How could this be done? I tried doing

```
train_data = [x for x in data[0] if data[1][x] < window_start]
```

but this does not work.

lets say that `window_size` will be `1514851201` so my desired output would be `[0,1]`

Comment: Do you get an `IndexError`? Specify your error please

Comment: Can you please share desired output?

Comment: @Haytam I get TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float, I realise that it is probably due to fact that x does not represent and index

Comment: We have to suppose that `data` is `list_of_values`? And what is `window_start`?

Comment: So you need to put the correct examples in your question so that we can't try the code.

Comment: Is a simple iteration and IF ? try more time with simple code, then try on list comprehesion if you want, because it seems you dont understand how it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of mistakes in your code. **First** of all you were looking for the data in the `data` list that you had declared as `list_of_values`, and, **secondly**, your sample `list_of_values` had 10 items in `list_of_values[0]` but only 9 in `list_of_values[1]`

You can do this:

```
list_of_values = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [1514764800, 1514851200, 1514937600, 1515024000, 1515110400, 1515196800, 1515283200, 1515369600, 1515456000]]

window_start = 1514851201

train_data = [x for x in list_of_values[0] if list_of_values[1][x] < window_start]

print(train_data)
```

The output will be:

```
[0, 1]
```

Comment: You removed the `9` from the first list, which causes an error.

Comment: @Haytam Yes, I was going to specify that by editing the answer

Comment: Note that the OP's error is somehow `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float`... So the above is probably just a copy-paste issue... Probably the whole thing is because that code doesn't raise this error, so who knows... <sigh>

Answer (score 0):

Your data[0] length is 10 and data[1] length is 9 so When you run your tried code you will get `Index out of range` error so you have to add another if condition  that checks if x is not bigger than data[1]'s count before `data[1][x] < window_start`

```
data = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], [1514764800, 1514851200, 1514937600, 1515024000, 1515110400, 1515196800, 1515283200, 1515369600, 1515456000]]

train_data = [x for x in data[0] if data[0].index(x) < len(data[1]) if data[1][x] < 1514851201 ]
print(train_data)
```

Output :

```
[0, 1]
```

Comment: Even there is a trailing `,` ,with no value after comma, in the end program give `Index out of range`

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that it suggests that it's a copy-paste problem because the OP didn't report an `IndexError`...

Comment: Indeed it is a copy-paste error, there should be an additional value in data[1]